# filter where the last value is not status = 'cancel' with cte and subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

```
CREATE TABLE origin_polis (
    cif INT,
    no_polis TEXT,
    status TEXT,
    tgl_produksi DATE,
    tgl_awal DATE,
    tgl_akhir DATE
);
```

```
INSERT INTO origin_polis (cif, no_polis, status, tgl_produksi, tgl_awal, tgl_akhir)
VALUES
    (100, 'aaa', 'new', '2020-01-13', '2019-02-19', '2022-05-16'),
    (100, 'aaa', 'extend', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-19', '2023-03-13'),
    (100, 'aab', 'new', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-20', '2023-03-15'),
    (101, 'aba', 'new', '2019-05-17', '2019-01-25', '2023-01-15'),
    (101, 'abb', 'new', '2021-06-18', '2020-06-24', '2023-01-10'),
    (102, 'abc', 'new', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-13', '2022-01-13'),
    (102, 'abc', 'extend', '2022-01-17', '2022-01-15', '2023-01-13'),
    (102, 'abc', 'cancel', '2022-01-17', '2022-01-15', '2023-01-13'),
    (103, 'abd', 'new', '2022-04-19', '2022-03-15', '2023-01-14'),
    (103, 'abd', 'cancel', '2022-04-19', '2022-03-15', '2023-01-14'),
    (103, 'abe', 'new', '2022-06-25', '2022-07-10', '2023-01-29'),
    (104, 'aca', 'new', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-01', '2023-09-04'),
    (104, 'aca', 'change', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-01', '2023-09-04'),
    (104, 'aca', 'cancel', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-01', '2023-09-04'),
    (104, 'aca', 'renew', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-01', '2023-10-04'),
    (104, 'acb', 'new', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-02', '2023-10-05'),
    (105, 'ada', 'new', '2022-02-02', '2022-02-01', '2023-08-04'),
    (105, 'ada', 'change', '2022-02-04', '2022-02-01', '2023-08-04'),
    (105, 'ada', 'cancel', '2022-02-06', '2022-02-01', '2023-08-04'),
    (105, 'ada', 'renew', '2022-02-10', '2022-02-01', '2023-09-08'),
    (105, 'ada', 'cancel', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-01', '2023-09-08'),
    (105, 'ada', 'renew', '2022-02-13', '2022-02-10', '2023-10-09'),
    (105, 'ada', 'change', '2022-02-15', '2022-02-10', '2023-11-10');
```

I want make a query in PostgreSQL so the output is

| cif | no_polis | status | tgl_produksi | tgl_awal | tgl_akhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | aca | new | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-09-04 |
| 104 | aca | change | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-09-04 |
| 104 | aca | cancel | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-09-04 |
| 104 | aca | renew | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-10-04 |
| 105 | ada | change | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-01 | 2023-08-04 |
| 105 | ada | cancel | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-01 | 2023-08-04 |
| 105 | ada | renew | 2022-02-10 | 2022-02-01 | 2023-09-08 |
| 105 | ada | cancel | 2022-02-11 | 2022-02-01 | 2023-09-08 |
| 105 | ada | renew | 2022-02-13 | 2022-02-10 | 2023-10-09 |
| 105 | ada | change | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-10 | 2023-11-10 |

The rules to get the desired output:

1. select the no_polis column that has exists status = 'cancel' in it
2. after that, filter where the last tgl_produksi is not status = 'cancel'

To get the first rules:

```
select *
from origin_polis t1
where exists (select *
            from origin_polis t2
            where t1.no_polis = t2.no_polis
            and status = 'cancel');
```

How do I get the second rules to be included in the query,
first rule done, and then filter again with the second rule?

Comment: Why is the first row in your sample output?  By your rules, I would think that only the second row (ACA Change on 2022-01-04) correspond to the cancellation on 2022-01-06.

Comment: Because I would like to returns all the output where all no_polis have existing status = 'cancel',
If the no_polis dont have status = 'cancel' then exclude it,
the first row included in the output, because no_polis = 'ACA' have status = 'cancel' in it, and I would like to show all the output from  no_polis = 'ACA'

Answer (score 0):

Your description is somewhat lacking, but from the data and results is appears looking to apply the rules to the combination of (cif, no_polis). If this is incorrect then you need to dramatically update the question.  

You can get what with: (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kp0fLLxB))

```
with last_cancel(cif, no_polis, tgl_produksi) as
     (select cif, no_polis, max(tgl_produksi)                       -- Rule 1: exists a status 'cancel'; get the last such status                         
        from origin_polis 
       where status = 'cancel'
       group by cif, no_polis 
     ) --select * from last_cancel;
select *
  from origin_polis op
  where (op.cif, op.no_polis) in (select lc.cif, lc.no_polis         -- Rule 2: Identify rows with a later non 'cancel' status         
                                    from last_cancel lc
                                   where lc.cif  = op.cif
                                     and lc.no_polis = op.no_polis
                                     and exists (select null             
                                                   from origin_polis t3
                                                  where (t3.cif, t3.no_polis) = (lc.cif, lc.no_polis)
                                                    and t3.status <> 'cancel'
                                                    and t3.tgl_produksi > lc.tgl_produksi
                                                )  
                                 )  
order by op.cif, op.no_polis, op.tgl_produksi;
```